# Error of In App Purchase

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have completed all the steps for In App Purchase.

However, when the xcode program execute this below line code.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:[SKPayment paymentWithProduct:productID]];
```

Error occurs and keeps on the same error.

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier:
>   (null)'

How to solve this problem?

Would any experienced xcode developer share the complete steps for In App Purchase?

Answer (score 0):

Check you bundle identifier, if it is same as set in for that application.

This error comes only when bundle identifier is not set correctly.

Hope it helps you......

Comment: check bundle identifier in you info.plist

Comment: Is it correct to type Product ID without Bundle ID in the setting of itunes connect?

Comment: com.appsws.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} is not correct?  Should I type com.appsws.BeHappy instead?

Comment: No it doesn't help to change that. ${PRODUCT_NAME} is taken from a field that you can change. It is Build Settings (a tab) => Packaging (a group) => Product Name. I'm not sure an incorrect product name is the cause of the original problem, but this is where you can change it.